How to inject DbContext into ILogger for custom database logging provider?
I'm trying to implement custom database logging provider in .NET Core.
I have my ApplicationDbContext.
Logging provider:
[ProviderAlias("Database")]
public class DatabaseLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IDisposable? _onChangeToken;
    private DatabaseLoggerOptions _currentConfig;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DatabaseLogger> _loggers = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DatabaseLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<DatabaseLoggerOptions> config, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _onChangeToken = config.OnChange(updatedConfig => _currentConfig = updatedConfig);
        _currentConfig = config.CurrentValue;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) =>
        _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new(name, GetCurrentConfig, _serviceProvider));

    private DatabaseLoggerOptions GetCurrentConfig() => _currentConfig;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _onChangeToken?.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

ILogger implementation:
internal class DatabaseLogger(string category, Func<DatabaseLoggerOptions> getCurrentConfiguration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : ILogger
{
    private class ScopeDisposable(Action disposeAction) : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action _disposeAction = disposeAction;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _disposeAction.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new();
    private readonly AsyncLocal<DatabaseLoggerParameters?> _scopeData = new();
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull
    {
        if (state is DatabaseLoggerParameters scopeData)
            _scopeData.Value = scopeData;

        // Return a disposable object to end the scope when disposed.
        return new ScopeDisposable(() => _scopeData.Value = default);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return (getCurrentConfiguration().CategoryToLogLevel.TryGetValue(category, out LogLevel value) ? value :
            getCurrentConfiguration().CategoryToLogLevel.GetValueOrDefault("Default")) <= logLevel;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
                return;

            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            ApplicationDbContext? _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            if (_context is not null)
            {
                DatabaseLoggerParameters? parameters = _scopeData.Value;
                string logMessage = $"Category: {category}{Environment.NewLine}";
                logMessage += $"Message: {formatter(state, exception!)}{Environment.NewLine}";

                if (exception != null)
                {
                    logMessage += $"Exception: {exception.Message}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    logMessage += $"Inner exception: {exception.InnerException?.Message ?? ""}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    logMessage += $"StackTrace: {exception.StackTrace}{Environment.NewLine}";
                }

                _context.ActivityLogs.Add(new()
                {
                    ActivityType = ActivityType.Unknown,
                    UserId = 1,
                    Message = logMessage,
                    On = DateTime.UtcNow
                }
                );

                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            scope.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}

And this is how I register the database logger:
    builder.AddConfiguration();

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, DatabaseLoggerProvider>();

    LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<DatabaseLoggerOptions, DatabaseLoggerProvider>(builder.Services);

The issue I'm facing is that, the code stops executing after ActivityLogs.Add method. I have a breakpoint in the catch clause and _context.SaveChanges() - and they're not hit. Also when I target my web api, to fetch some data, the request runs forever without returning anything. I assume that there is deadlock somewhere, but I don't know how to resolve it.
Any help is welcomed, thank you in advance :)

I wouldn't do that. DB is expensive and this is something that should be put to file which is not. Why do you want to store in DB?

@mattsharp I have file logger. But business requires logs also in database ...

Me personally, I would push back at that. There are plenty of ways to display/access file logs for display etc.

@mattsharp Customers have their own IT administration. They need UI preview of the logs. I think this is not the BEST approach, but it's decent. Only to figure out when and how deadlock occurs and how to resolve it.

Fair enough, thought id ask and give an opinion! I get you want to restrict the logs and this is the reason for it

@mattsharp using _lock, does not resolve the issue. I forgot to provide that part of the code, which I deleted it later..

Yea I had a think and couldn't see where you would use it (hence deleted my comment).

Not sure if this helps but I took the code you posted, added to an api project and it worked. I did remove a few things which I assume is where the error is. I removed the DatabaseLoggerOptions and the DatabaseLoggerParameters. I assume it is something around the DatabaseLoggerParameters rather than the options since that looks fine EDIT: I think I see it - maybe the fact its async and this is sync?

@mattsharp I will try something around your answer, and let you know. Thank you for your time :)

Note that EF Core has logging too, so in theory you can end up with endless cycle when you try to save logs to database, which produces logs which results in trying saving logs into the db ...

Also consider looking into 3rd party loggers like Serilog which have such functionality.
